# How To Obtain MP3 Metadata/ID3 tag From URI Source (not StorageFile)?

Tags: c#, uwp, mp3

I'm creating a [MediaSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource) directly from a URI which serves an MP3 file:

```
MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(urlStr));
var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
await mediaSource.OpenAsync();
mediaPlayer.Source = mediaSource;
MyXamlMediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
```

Everything loads fine and it plays back fine.  But how can I obtain the metadata?  I can only find documentation on obtaining a `MusicProperties` object from a `StorageFile`. Creating a file first is not an option as it takes way too long.

Comment: You might find [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-supported-metadata-cues) helpful.

Comment: There's a lot of good info in that document. Unfortunately my source isn't a HTTP Live Stream and cannot be made into an AdaptiveMediaSource. I don't think the framework can extract an ID3 tag from a MediaSource.  The best I can do is manually find what I need the hard way.  [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399604/how-to-read-id3v2-tag) helped.